# Using SPARQL to query DBPedia and create a graph in Python

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to this so I will sum up my problem and my approach.

I want to evaluate the performance of a graph traversing algorithm (currently simple as BFS) and use ML to predict the performance/runtime for a certain query. In order to do this, I would like to create a simple but big graph from DBPedia where each note is an article and if that article links to another one, they are connected on the graph. Then I would create an algorithm to find if there exist a path between 2 node whose length is bound by a certain threshold. After that ML is used to predict the performance of that algorithm.

For the SPARQL query, I can think of this very simple query:

```
    SELECT ?origin ?link  
      WHERE { 
     ?main    a  owl:Thing.
     ?linkto  a  owl:Thing.
     ?main    dbo:wikiPageWikiLink  ?linkto.
     ?main rdfs:label ?origin.
     ?linkto rdfs:label ?link.
     FILTER ( LANG ( ?origin) = 'en' )
     FILTER ( LANG ( ?link) = 'en' )
    }
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is it feasible to create a giant graph with every English Wikipedia article?
2. How do I import the query above to Python to create a graph?
3. I can see a problem that when article A links to B and the B also links to A, the vertex will be duplicate in the query, how do I remove that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) what is a "giant" graph per article? and no, I doubt it will work with the public SPARQL endpoint because i) the number of rows per request is limited to `10000` and there is also the chance for a timeout with larger offset values - luckily you can download the whole dump and work on your local triple store or file system

Comment: 2) rdflib is one of the APIs, for remote SPARQL its SPARQLWrapper module has to be used.

Comment: 3) that has to be done in a post-processing if you're running multiple SPARQL queries - even `

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion! by giant I mean like 6+ millions of nodes, how big would that be? is it possible to process that in Python?